# Is there any transformation that connects functions whose extremum are same?

Tags: real-analysis, real-algebraic-geometry

I wonder if there is a transformation between functions whose extremum are same, finding extremum of general function becomes easy a bit, but is it known already?

For example, $f(x) = x^2$ has its extrema at $\langle x \rangle = 0$. It is so simple already, but we know there are lots of function whose extrema is at same point. $f(x) = a x^2 + c$, $f(x) = ax^3 + c$ and  $f(x) = \frac{a}{4} x^4 + \frac{b}{3} x^3 + \frac{c}{2} x^2 + d$ with $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ are minimum examples, I think. There are infinite examples, of course.

However, as a matter of practice, we would like to know whether an extrema is stable or not. This may add restriction. In the previous expample, $f(x) = ax^3 + c$ is not stable at $\langle x \rangle = 0$.

This amounts to a problem that finding functions whose derivatives have the same set of their roots and values of their derivative at the roots are positive.

I think maybe this is trivial in some areas like Algebraic Geometry, but I don't major in mathematics.

If you know something, please tell me.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by extremum? It seems to me that, for $a\ne0$, no function in the form $ax^3+c$ has extrema, global or otherwise.

Comment: I think stability is not simply needing 2nd derivatives to be positive. For example $y=x^4$ is stable at $x=0$, but its 1st, 2nd and 3rd derivatives are all zero there.

Comment: @Gae.S.  I'm sorry for that, I used a term "extremum" as "a set of roots of its derivative = 0".

Comment: Many sets of functions form (infinite-dimensional) vector spaces. This includes sets of functions with zeroes at particular values, and sets of differentiable functions with zero derivatives at particular values. Because they are vector spaces we know can add functions or multiply by scalars (real numbers) and get another function in the same set. We even have ways of defining "distance" between two functions. For a more detailed treatment of all this look up vector space and Hilbert space.